# Can a limited-days-per-week let confer a tenancy?

Tags: england-and-wales, tenancy-rules

Alice has let a property to Bob but requires it to be available for herself on Saturdays and Sundays. (Or perhaps merely Wednesdays.)

Can Bob in any circumstances then be said to have been granted a tenancy of the property or would the blocked off days preclude this?

Comment: This highly depends on how the contract is written

Comment: This also depends on the purpose of the property- residences have specific laws thst commercial property does not.

Comment: Is Bob lodging with Alice? Or does she live elsewhere?

Comment: So Bob moves himself and everything he owns out every week?

Comment: @Seekinganswers You allege things that are just not in the question again. Street v Montford is all about "Is this a lease?" and only *one* of the judges there said anything about exclusive possession. You ask if "You rent weekdays, but not weekdays" precludes exclusive possession, which would depend on what the contract contains or not contains: Do you have to move out every friday and move in on monday? Do you just grant access to the landlord on the weekends? Is there a use limit for the landlord for the weekends (e.g. is it for renovations or any use? That's all *what's in the contract*!

Answer (score 1):

QUESTION:  Can Bob in any circumstances then be said to have granted exclusive possession of the property?

ANSWER: Yes, for those days Bob has exclusive possession of the whole property and Alice is not present, but he just doesn’t have exclusive possession of it throughout the entire week.

Comment: @Seekinganswers, you stipulated "*in any circumstances*", so on a daily basis, for those specific days that Bob has exclusive possession, yes.  For the days that Alice has access, no.  If you consider a full week instead of each day, (or duration of the agreement) then the answer would also be no.  If you expect a better answer than that then some context is needed.